# Trigger Actions Framework Flow Error

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

I am at a loss as to why I can't get a basic Autolaunched Flow to work with the Trigger Actions Framework (https://github.com/mitchspano/apex-trigger-actions-framework).
I have an Autolaunched Flow that is super basic, all I want to do is populate a field with the Salesforce ID if it is NULL when entered.
[image]

I am following the video here, which uses `newList`, `oldList` and `newListAfterFlow`, but now the documentation refers to record and oldRecord.
Looking at the code, I am pretty sure I still need to use newList/oldList/newListAfterFlow, but everything I try is failing.
The error I am getting is:

> Review the errors on this page.
> TF_TRG_ClientLink: execution of AfterInsert caused by: TriggerActionFlow.TriggerActionFlowException: null is not a valid name of a class that extends FlowTriggerRecord
> Class.TriggerActionFlow.getFlowTriggerRecord: line 259, column 1
> Class.TriggerActionFlow: line 181, column 1 Class.TriggerActionFlow: line 89, column 1 Class.MetadataTriggerHandler: line 224, column 1
> Class.MetadataTriggerHandler: line 32, column 1
> Class.TriggerBase.run: line 51, column 1 Trigger.TF_TRG_ClientLink: line 10, column 1

I am absolutely befuddled - if anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I turn the flow off, then there is no error, so it is not anything to do with validation rules, etc.

Comment: by hacking the APEX, this is where the error is ... it is hitting the one with "_BBB"

`private FlowTriggerRecord getFlowTriggerRecord() {
        FlowTriggerRecord result;
        if (flowTriggerRecordClassName == null) {
            throw new TriggerActionFlowException(
                flowTriggerRecordClassName + INVALID_FLOW_TRIGGER_RECORD_CLASS + '_BBB'
            );
}`

Comment: That means your `flowTriggerRecordClassName` is coming as null, but as we dont know how that is set, as this is not set from the framework link given above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for checking out the framework!

I would recommend updating to the newest version of the Trigger Actions Framework.

A few months ago there was a pretty significant breakthrough where we are able to greatly improve the performance and ergonomics of the flows. I wrote a blog post about it here - https://www.mitchspano.com/blog/Trigger_Action_Flow

In the updated versions, the ergonomics match record Triggered flows almost perfectly - they will be familiar to any admin.

Check out the latest package download link and the updated "Support for Flows" section of the readme:

https://github.com/mitchspano/apex-trigger-actions-framework

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same problem. For some reason, flowTriggerRecordClassName is null, but I also think there's some problem with TRIGGER_RECORDS_VARIABLE = 'triggerRecords'; shouldn't this be 'newList'?

EDIT: Additionally, I noticed there's an issue with FlowTriggerRecord Class Name field on Object Trigger Setting. Which class should extend FlowTriggerRecord?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/190713)